# Yii2 - custom order in the models get relationship

Tags: yii, yii2

What is the correct way to make the custom order in the models get relationship? Is it possible to do this? This is my current code:

```
   public function getBoardPosts()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(BoardPosts::className(), ['topic_id' => 'id'])->orderBy('order ASC');
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Here is an example from the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#dynamic-relational-query):

```
class Customer extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function getBigOrders($threshold = 100)
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::className(), ['customer_id' => 'id'])
            ->where('subtotal > :threshold', [':threshold' => $threshold])
            ->orderBy('id');
    }
}
```

Please note that you may have to quote the field (or better yet name your columns using non-SQL words):

```
return $this->hasMany(BoardPosts::className(), ['topic_id' => 'id'])->orderBy('`order` ASC');
```